# Using cache for two projects at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-web-api

I am a beginner in the ASP.NET Core. Now, I am building a diploma project "EducationManagementSystem for teachers". Of course, I understand, that it's a difficult project for beginners, but in the process of development I ran into a problem.
So, the problem is:
I have 3 projects with the same solution:

1. ASP.NET Core Web API;
2. ASP.NET Core MVC;
3. DataAccess (c# library for database entities etc).

So, in the web API application, I'm interacting with the DataAccess and manipulating some data.
Client, using the MVC project and accordingly UI, interacts with the WEB API and gets some data, deletes, puts, etc.
, I use IMemoryCache interface for caching results of the MVC controller on the server side and check if there is a cache, the user gets it from the cache, otherwise, get it from the database (code below).

```
[ActionName("students")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Students()
{
    userId ??= HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name)!;

    cacheKey_students = $"studentsOf_{userId}";

    var studentsData = await _cacheService.GetOrSetAsync(cacheKey_students, async () =>
    {
        var coursesList = await GetCourses(userId);
        var squadsList = await GetSquads(userId);

        var studentsVM = new StudentsPageViewModel
        {
            coursesList = coursesList,
            squadsList = squadsList
        };

        return studentsVM;
    }, TimeSpan.FromDays(7));

    return PartialView(studentsData);
}
```

But if some data has changed before expire time of the cache, the cache won't be refreshed, and to solve this problem I use custom CacheService (int the DataAccess project) for getting, setting, and invalidating cache (code below):

```cs
public class CacheService : ICacheService
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

    public CacheService(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }

    public async Task<T> GetOrSetAsync<T>(string key, Func<Task<T>> getItemFunc, TimeSpan expirationTime)
    {
        if (!_memoryCache.TryGetValue(key, out T item))
        {
            item = await getItemFunc();

            if (item != null)
            {
                var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
                    .SetAbsoluteExpiration(expirationTime);

                _memoryCache.Set(key, item, cacheEntryOptions);
            }
        }

        return item;
    }

    public bool InvalidateCache(string key)
    {
        try
        {
            _memoryCache.Remove(key);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I use this service in the MVC project and Web API project at the same time (with `services.AddSingleton`) it does not work, when I invalidate the cache from the Web API project (when some data has changed). So, I figured out that they are using different cache memory.

My question is: how to deal with it?

Is it something like Redis or there is another way? I think maybe we can create some listener in the MVC project, that will listen to the Web API project, and when some WEB API controller says "Rerfresh the cache" the MVC project will do it.

Comment: The memory cache exists in the context of each running project, yes there are 2 caches running in your solution. Redis will be a great option and if you use Docker/Docker Compose this is as easy as adding it to the Compose file and letting both your applications talk to it. If you don't want to do this, you could use your WebAPI project to handle the caching and add an endpoint for your MVC app to communicate with it. If you ask me, Redis is the better option mainly for the scalability.

Comment: Note my response makes it seem like you have to use Docker to use Redis, you don't have to - just makes local development simpler

Comment: @mattsharp Thanks a lot for the answer, I think it's the best option for the situations like this

Comment: Before talking about your question, could you pls let us know that why you require to design "MVC + WEB API + Data Access" 3 projects for a "EducationManagementSystem for teachers"? Per my understanding, each school doesn't have so many teachers and I'm afraid an MVC project is enough for your scenario. If so, session should be enough for you to store the hot data... Redis is a good option for Distributed application system, and is it necessary for us to design a Distributed structure? Just my humble opinion... Pls ignore if it makes you confused.

Comment: @TinyWang Thanks for answer, I am agree with you, I was thinking about this, but I prefered this variant because in my opinion, there is a possibility that the application will expand and most importantly, that there will be a need for a mobile application, and accordingly I will be able to adjust everything much easier for a mobile application using a ready-made API

Comment: thanks for your kind reply, for a distribute structure, using memory database like redis cosmosdb would be a great solution